# Angular2 data binding not work with Chinese property name?

Tags: angular

Here is my code:
the template is:

```
<div>
    时间: {{DataContext.时间}}
</div>
```

Here '时间' is Chinese char which means time,
and in the typescript file. I define a DataContext property.

```
export class TestClass {
    @Input()
    DataContext:any;
}
```

But it not work, I got a error. Here is the error message, "Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character {{时间}}......"

I really need it support Chinese char, because the json data from a old system, and all the data's properties use Chinese char.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I guess you need to create a bug report.

Comment: Yes, I also report it here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13265

Answer (score 1):

I ran to same problem and I created service/pipe which converts characters to Unicode which is as below. Hope it helps(Although this is not right way but temporarily solve problem)

```
var _escape_overrides = { 0x00:'\uFFFD',0x80:'\u20AC',0x82:'\u201A',0x83:'\u0192',0x84:'\u201E',0x85:'\u2026',0x86:'\u2020',0x87:'\u2021',0x88:'\u02C6',0x89:'\u2030',0x8A:'\u0160',0x8B:'\u2039',0x8C:'\u0152',0x8E:'\u017D',0x91:'\u2018',0x92:'\u2019',0x93:'\u201C',0x94:'\u201D',0x95:'\u2022',0x96:'\u2013',0x97:'\u2014',0x98:'\u02DC',0x99:'\u2122',0x9A:'\u0161',0x9B:'\u203A',0x9C:'\u0153',0x9E:'\u017E',0x9F:'\u0178' }; 

function escapeHtml(str){
    return str.replace(/([\u0000-\uD799]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uFFFF])/g, function(c) {
        var c1 = c.charCodeAt(0);
        // ascii character, use override or escape
        if( c1 <= 0xFF ) return (c1=_escape_overrides[c1])?c1:escape(c).replace(/%(..)/g,"&#x$1;");
        // utf8/16 character
        else if( c.length == 1 ) return "&#" + c1 + ";"; 
        // surrogate pair
        else if( c.length == 2 && c1 >= 0xD800 && c1 <= 0xDBFF ) return "&#" + ((c1-0xD800)*0x400 + c.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00 + 0x10000) + ";"
        // no clue .. 
        else return "";
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and please give me a full sample code, where to use this pipe, and Here "时间" is a property of DataContext, I wonder if convert it, the data binding will not work.

Comment: I have tried it like this `<div>{{时间 | UnicodeConvert}}</div>', here "UnicodeConvert" is the new pipe with your code , I also use the pipe just return "time" , it still doesn't work. Any ideas?